# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'integer'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, type-conversion

Here is MyCode:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var EmployeerId = SessionPersister.Email_ID;
    //Convert.ToInt32(EmployeerId);
    int.Parse(EmployeerId);
    db.Job_Det.OrderByDescending(j => j.Job_ID).ToList().Where(x => x.Employeer_ID = EmployeerId);
    return View();
}
```

i tried many conversion methods..but i am failed to covert the above string to integer.

Comment: Why you know it is failed?

Comment: If `EmployeerId` is `string`, then you need to convert it to `int` first

Comment: `x => x.Employeer_ID = EmployeerId ` Only one equal sign? Also, your int.parse result does not has a variable to store.

Comment: Yes,var Employeerid is string and need to convert it to int... as i tried many conversion methods but does't effect.

Comment: @JaffarHayat: It doesn't change the type of the variable, no - it can't. Instead, those methods *return* a new value.

Comment: @jon Skeet please tell me how to convert it...?

Comment: @JaffarHayat Try EmployeerId=Int32.Parse(EmployeerId);  Secondly In above example you didn't stored your parsed result anywhere.

Comment: See my answer - or the other ones. As an aside, I would suggest that if this sort of thing is confusing you, you should probably take a step back and learn the basics of the language before going into LINQ, MVC etc. Console apps are (IMO) a much friendlier environment to get started in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public ActionResult Index()
{
    var EmployeerId = SessionPersister.Email_ID;
    //Convert.ToInt32(EmployeerId);
   int EmpId=int.Parse(EmployeerId);
    db.Job_Det.OrderByDescending(j => j.Job_ID).ToList().Where(x => x.Employeer_ID = EmpId);
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just calling `Convert.ToInt32(EmployeerId)` or `int.Parse(EmployeerId)` doesn't change the type of `EmployeerId` - both methods will *return* a value that you'd need to store in a new variable.

You're *also* not doing anything with your query result at the moment - and by calling `ToList()` before the `Where` call, you're fetching all the data and then filtering locally, which is a bad idea.

Finally, in your query you're trying to *assign* a value instead of comparing it; you want the `==` operator instead of `=`.

I suspect you want something like:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string employerIdText = SessionPersister.Email_ID;
    int employerId = int.Parse(employerIdText);
    var jobs = db.Job_Det
        .OrderByDescending(j => j.Job_ID)
        .Where(x => x.Employeer_ID == employerId)
        .ToList();
    return View(jobs);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much... it's working now, Great :)

Answer (score 4):

you arent storing the result of `int.Parse(EmployeerId);` it doesnt change employerid to an int.. you need to keep it as an int variable such as

```
eid = int.Parse(EmployeerId);
```

then replace `x => x.Employeer_ID = EmployeerId` with x `=> x.Employeer_ID == eid`, unless you really did mean to replace all the employeer_IDs with the new value.

Answer (score 1):

*`int.Parse(EmployeerId)`;* does not change the *EmployeerId*. You need to use another variable for the int value.

```
var iEmployeerId = int.Parse(EmployeerId);
```